# How can I prevent anonymous classes in a JaCoCo coverage report?

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I current migrate to JaCoCo. In my old system there was one line per source file.

In the code coverage report that I receive from JaCoCo there are a large count of anonymous classes. Is it possible to summarize the result from anonymous classes to its parent class?

I use the current version 0.7.1.

I want one line per source file in the code coverage report.